# JBoss AS7 - Deploy an application in an exploded folder using CLI

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I have an EAR application as a exploded folder. I want to deploy this application to JBoss AS7 using CLI.

When I try to deploy the application using this command:

```
deploy application_path/myApplication.ear
```

I got this error message:

```
application_path/myApplication.ear is a directory.
```

If the application is packaged in a `.EAR`file, I can deploy the application using the command above without any problem, but I can't deploy it when the application is in a exploded folder.

I also can deploy the exploded folder application creating a `myApplication.dodeploy`file in the deployments folder.

Is there any option to deploy the application using CLI if the application is in a exploded folder?

Comment: A google for "jboss 7 exploded cli deploy" gives plenty of hints towards "no". https://developer.jboss.org/thread/173331 . But where people say no, other people invent workarounds as this linked thread proves.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the folder to myApplication, i.e. remove ".ear".
Then 
deploy application_path/myApplication

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. When I tried to deploy the application without the `.ear`, I got the same error, `application_path/myApplication is a directory.`